# How to replace these Methods for service

Tags: android

I am working on a service in Android. I do not know how to replace these methods of activity with a service.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    checkPlayServices();

    // Resuming the periodic location updates
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() && mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
        startLocationUpdates();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    stopLocationUpdates();
}
```

please tell me how I replace them

Comment: You don't "replace them". There is no equivalent to those actions. Instead, you call methods like `checkPlayServices()` in other places where it makes sense, given the combination of business logic of your app and the nature of the `Service` API.

Answer (score 0):

this may help you to achieve callbacks to your service from activity

Write this in your Activity life cycle methods.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("com.example.ON_RESUME");//change this for appropriate callback
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

change your service like

```
class YourService extends Service {
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        //Do your stuff
        return null;
    }


    private void onResume() {
        //do your stuff
    }

    private void onStop() {
        //do your stuff
    }

    private void onPause() {
        //do your stuff
    }

    public static class ActivityLifeCycleReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        public String ACTION_ON_RESUME = "com.example.ON_RESUME";
        public String ACTION_ON_STOP = "com.example.ON_STOP";
        public String ACTION_ON_PAUSE = "com.example.ON_PAUSE";

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (ACTION_ON_PAUSE.equals(action)) {
                onPause();
            } else if (ACTION_ON_RESUME.equals(action)) {
                onResume();
            } else if (ACTION_ON_STOP.equals(action)) {
                onResume();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally register receiver in MANIFEST.

```
    <receiver android:name=".YourService$ActivityLifeCycleReceiver">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="com.example.ON_RESUME"/>
            <action android:name="com.example.ON_STOP"/>
            <action android:name="com.example.ON_PAUSE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```